# Laravel Passport works fine on PostMan, but returns 401 inside the react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, laravel-passport

When I make my Axios call inside of the react native app, it returns 401. However, when I grab the parsed header inside of the Network tab it shows:

```
     const config = { 
        method: "POST",
        baseURL: API_URL, 
        data:request_data,
        headers: { 
             'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ token
           }
        }


  let  data  = await axios('user_update_profile',config)
  console.log(data)  //return 401 Unauthorized Error
```

Any idea how to fix this?
I am using Laravel version 6

Comment: Where do you set the token?

Comment: I set token in token variable

Comment: Yes, where do you set it in your app?

Comment: I persist the latest token in redux reducer that I get in login API

Comment: this token is working fine in Postman

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in your browser to make sure that the Bearer token is being set correctly?

Comment: Also, I recommend using Laravel Telescope to debug your requests. https://laravel.com/docs/telescope

Comment: yes token is set correctly

Comment: Again, I recommend you using Laravel Telescope. After installation, run the Postman request and the axios request and compare the two. You can view a request by clicking the *eye* symbol in the Requests tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to set headers in Axios 
Wrong-way :

```
     const config = { 
        method: "POST",
        baseURL: API_URL, 
        data:request_data,
        headers: { 
             'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ token
           }
        }


  let  data  = await axios('user_update_profile',config)
```

So the Correct way is

```
  let  data  = await axios.post(API_URL+'user_update_profile',request_data,{
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
  }
  })
  // console.log('----cheers---------',data)
dispatch(userUpdateProfileSuccess(data))
```

Thanks